# Did not print false when the result is less than base

Tags: javascript

I doing some practice with find power one number is power of another number. When I reach to `base = 1` and `result = 2`, it does not print out `false` for me. What can I do to fix the issue?
Here is my code:

```
let base = 1;
let result = 2;
powerOf(base, result);
function powerOf(base, result){
    if (base == 1){
        result == 1;
    }
    let powerOf = 1;
    while (powerOf < result){
        powerOf = powerOf * base;
    }
    console.log(powerOf = result);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the issue has nothing to do with the return value. it should be printing false int eh console.

Comment: You are making quite a mess between assignment (with `=`) and comparison (with `==`)

Comment: Well, probably using the while loop inside the function which has to return something isn't a good thing. Instead you can all the `powerOf` function in a while loop (outside its definition of course)

Comment: Because you don't have the condition for `return false`. Also the `result` will always hold the value `2`, so it goes to **infinite loop**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use powerOf as a variable to store your power result, when base is 1, powerOf must be 1, you don't need to enter the while loop

```js
let base = 1;
let result = 2;

console.log(powerOf(base, result));

function powerOf(base, result) {
  let powerOf = 1;
  while (powerOf < result && base != 1) {
    powerOf = powerOf * base;
  }

  return powerOf == result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (base == 1){
  result == 1; // comparing, not assigning
}
```

This **does not** assign `result` a value of 1. It *compares* result to 1. So in this case your while loop will never exit.

```js
while (powerOf < result){ // powerOf is still 1, result is still 2.
  powerOf = powerOf * base; // 1 * 1 is still 1.
  powerOf == result; // This doesn't do anything.
}
```

Comment: Yes, fix the issue of having useless line of code by remove ```powerOf == result;```. But, like I said, I am not sure how to give the other compare where base is 1 and result is greater than 1

Comment: The useless line of code isn't the problem. As explained above, you're not assigning result a value of 1 as you appear to be attempting, so your while loop never exits.